# What is the future of dl() function in php?

Tags: php

I am reading in the php documentation that dl function will be deprecated. So does that mean we should stop using the dl function from scripts.

If that's the case then how can someone load the .so from php scripts.

Or I am completely missing something.

Comment: They have already removed it PHP 5.3, yes you should avoid using it.

Comment: See the PHP manual: http://php.net/dl#refsect1-function.dl-changelog

Comment: Loading `.so` at runtime isn't possible anymore but hey! how many times you used it?

Comment: My use case is like for some scripts I need only x.so and for some I need only y.so and for some I need only z.so.  With dl I could finely control this behaviour, but now the only choice I am left with is to load it from php.ini. So now whether the script need the .so file or not..it will be always loaded and it will waste a lot of init time.

Answer (score 1):

You should stop using it, because it is deprecated and already removed. You should use your `php.ini` file in order to configure extensions on your server.

You can then use `extension_loaded('extension_name')` to see whether an extension is loaded and throw an error if it's not.

Comment: So it means that you can only load the extension before the executing phase of the script starts. And that means you can only do it at the init time of php, when it tries to look up at the .ini file.  And you need to do something like "extension=abc.so" in your ini file to load any extension.

Comment: Yes. And using dl() is not an option since it will not be available.

Answer (score 1):

In situations where `dl()` was used to verify an extension was loaded, you can use `extension_loaded(string $name)` instead.

"Old"

```
if(dl('extension_name')) {

}
```

"New"

```
if(extension_loaded('extension_name')) {

}
```